# Show that Set $A = \{\frac{m}{m+n}:m,n \in \mathbb{N}\}$ is such that $\sup A=1$

Tags: real-analysis

Consider the set, $A = \{\frac{m}{m+n}:m,n \in \mathbb{N}\}$

I am confused at how to get $\sup A =1$ and was wondering if someone could explain the steps to me.

Thank-you

Comment: you have to show that $1$ is an upper lper limit of $A$ and that there is no smaller upper limit.

Comment: @GregordeCillia: Upper _bound_.

Comment: Hello, you need to check two things. First, is it true that $1$ is at least as large as every element of $A$? And secondly, is there another number $x$, which is at least as large as every element of $A$, but with $x<1$?

Answer (score 1):

The supremum is by definition the smallest upper bound of the set. So:

- Show that $1$ is an upper bound. That is show $m/(m+n) \le 1$ for all $m,n$.
- Show that there is no upper bound smaller than $1$. Assume you have some $q < 1$. Show it is not an upper bound by exhibiting $m,n$ such that $m/(m+n) > q$. (Note it works with $n=1$ for a suitable $m$.)

Answer (score 0):

Since $m,n$ are natural numbers we have $m,n \ge 1$ and so 
${m \over m+n} \le {m+n \over m+n} = 1$, so 1 is an upper bound.

Now fix $n=1$ and notice that $\lim_{m \to \infty} {m \over 1+m} = 1$.

So, for any $\epsilon >0$ we can find $(m,n)$ such that
${m \over m+n} > 1-\epsilon$.

Hence $1$ is the least upper bound, that is, the $\sup$.

Answer (score 0):

As @GregordeCillia pointed out, it seems that in your notation $0 \notin \mathbb{N}$.

**Hint:**

- First, show that $\forall x \in A. x \leqslant 1$.
- Second, give an example of a sequence $(x_k)_{k \in \mathbb{N}} \subset A$ such that $\lim_{k \to \infty} x_k = 1$.

I hope this helps $\ddot\smile$

Comment: In his definition $0$ is certainly not an elent of $\mathbb{R}$, otherwise you would divide by 0 for $m=n=0$

Comment: @GregordeCillia Great, thanks!